# SQL - Grouping segments for AVGs and COUNTs

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a database of Parking Citations, I wrote the following syntax to display a segment for each Citation that falls within certain ViolFine parameters:

```
SELECT Citation, Make, ViolCode, ViolDate, ViolFine
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN '01. $0.00 - $50.00'
        WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN '02. $50.01 - $100.00'
        WHEN ViolFine > 100 THEN '03. larger than $100.00'  
      END AS ViolFineSegments
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
ORDER BY ViolDate DESC
```

Now I want to get results that GROUP each segment defined above. I used the below, but it appears to be grouping each distinct ViolFine with their corresponding total number of citations along with segment parameter:

```
SELECT AVG(ViolFine) AS AvgFine, COUNT(Citation) AS NumberViolations
    ,CASE 
        WHEN AVG(ViolFine) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN '01. $0.00 - $50.00'
        WHEN AVG(ViolFine) BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN '02. $50.01 - $100.00'
        WHEN AVG(ViolFine) > 100 THEN '03. larger than $100.00' 
      END AS ViolFineSegments
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
GROUP BY  ViolFine
ORDER BY ViolFine
```

Essentially, I want just want three rows for each group segment that displays the average citation and the count for each grouping and I'm sure how to proceed.

I also tried the below, but that just lists one long row where i would like three separate rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN '01. $0.00 - $50.00' END) '0-50',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN '02. $50.01 - $100.00' END) as '50-100',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ViolFine > 100 THEN '03. larger than $100.00' END) as '>100',
       AVG(CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN ViolFine END) as '0-50',
       AVG(CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN ViolFine END) as '50-100',
       AVG(CASE WHEN ViolFine > 100 THEN ViolFine END) as '>100'
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a editor in front of me, but you can use UNION ALL for every case statement that you have

```
    SELECT AVG(ViolFine) AS AvgFine, COUNT(Citation) AS NumberViolations, AVG(ViolFine) AS [01. $0.00 - $50.00]
    FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
    GROUP BY  ViolFine
    HAVING AVG(ViolFine) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AVG(ViolFine) AS AvgFine, COUNT(Citation) AS NumberViolations, AVG(ViolFine) AS [02. $50.01 - $100.00]    
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Segment using a `case` expression and group by that expression to get the average and count.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN '01. $0.00 - $50.00'         
     WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN '02. $50.01 - $100.00' 
     WHEN ViolFine > 100 THEN '03. larger than $100.00' 
END as fine_segment
,COUNT(*) as fine_count
,AVG(1.0*ViolFine) as avg_fine
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 0.00 AND 50.00 THEN '01. $0.00 - $50.00'         
              WHEN ViolFine BETWEEN 50.01 AND 100.00 THEN '02. $50.01 - $100.00' 
              WHEN ViolFine > 100 THEN '03. larger than $100.00' 
         END
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped, I wasn't sure about using the GROUP BY and WHEN clause.